# Installed 13.10 ubuntu in my HP laptop, after booting up, it doesn't the display

Tags: boot, 13.10

i installed 13.10 and installation completed successfully but the display doesn't come up after booting up from Ubuntu screen.
please help me troubleshoot this issue. ASAP

Comment: what shows on the screen while you boot up?Only black screen!

Comment: it is something like black screen, display without power connection and laptop is still running.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works for you. But one on my laptop (compaq) this happened and I just changed the display (you can find its key on keyboard) and my LCD turned on.
I hope your problem be as simple as mine

Comment: Thanks anyway, It is not display issue. previously it was working with 11.10 Ubuntu.